# How do I disable the cut button on excel 10 ribbon

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to disable the cut function/button on the ribbon. I have a situation where there are a number of formulae that are reliant on data input cells. If those cells are cut and pasted elsewhere the formula follows the cell. I have disabled right click and keyboard shortcut but cannot disable the ribbon cut function. I downloaded a spreadsheet from another thread with a similar requirement which had no cut button on the Home ribbon but cannot see any code to show how it was achieved. Soooo! If anyone can help it would be awesome.

Comment: Even if you disable the Ribbon and Cell Menu cut buttons, the users will still be able to use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.  You should protect your worksheet instead.

Comment: Make a copy of the file you downloaded and add a `.zip` extension to its file name. Open it and look for a `CustomUI` folder in it. You should be able to see how it was disabled by examining the ribbon XML document.